# Hiding sensitive information in files from user but not from shell scripts in linux

Tags: linux, shell

Consider a scenario where a user will be given a tool and the only operation user should be allowed to run the main script. Now tool uses some files to store sensitive information. What I want is that script should be able to access the data in the file but the user should not. The only access he should have is to run the script.

For a simple case lets consider the tool contains 2 files  main.sh as the script user can just run only not even read it and info_file which contains some sensitive information only that main.sh should be use that not the user.

This tool may be passed to different users on different machines.What are different ways of handling these kind of scenarios in linux.

Comment: This is off-topic here. Try asking this question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Set the script file and data file up with only root rwx and then set the user up with sudo permissions to only execute the file.

Comment: But what if user goes root in his own machine?